# Magento 2 migration tool sin atributos del cliente

Tags: mysql, magento2, data-atributos, migration

Tengo un inconveniente al migrar los datos de magento 1.7.x.x a magento 2.1.x que es ignorar algunos atributos del cliente como la cedula, en la tabla eav_attribute este es el dato que deseo ignorar,  (la siguiente imagen es de la tabla magento 1.7)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la documentación muestra cómo ignorar las columnas en el documento map-customer-xml de la siguiente forma

```
<ignore>
    <field>customer_entity.entity_type_id</field>
</ignore>
```

En map-eav.xml ignora columnas de la misma forma

```
<ignore>                
    <field>catalog_eav_attribute.is_required_in_admin_store</field>
</ignore>
```

Tengo la version migration tool 2.1.5 
En el directorio vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/
estos son los archivos que muestra para la configuración de la migración, en lo que he buscado no encuentro como, ni en cual puedo ignorar los atributos que necesito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias por su atención

Comment: Al parecer alguien tiene un problema exactamente igual al tuyo: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/115#issuecomment-282740694

Answer (score 0):

Para ignorar los atributos del cliente usamos el archivo eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist creamos una copia

```
cp eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist eav-attribute-groups.xml
```

En el nodo ignore colocamos los atributos que deseamos hay que tener cuidado con el tipo de atributo que coloquemos ejemplo

```
 <groups xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../groups.xsd">
<group name="ignore">
   <attribute type="catalog_product">msrp_enabled</attribute>
     <!-- ignore attributes -->
   <attribute type="customer">cedula</attribute>
    <!--  ignore end -->
</group>
</groups>
```

si el type es el indicado ignora el que deseas, de lo contrario no hara nada o ignorara en otro lugar 
Con el documento editado pasamos hacer la migración